# Rename Files Using List in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to rename a file using based on a list in excel such that column A has old file name and Column B has new file name. It worked for some files but its not renaming some files. 
THis is the macro that I used:

```
Sub RenameFiles()

Dim xDir As String

Dim xFile As String

Dim xRow As Long

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    .AllowMultiSelect = False

If .Show = -1 Then

    xDir = .SelectedItems(1)

    xFile = Dir(xDir & Application.PathSeparator & "*")

    Do Until xFile = ""

        xRow = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        xRow = Application.Match(xFile, Range("A:A"), 0)
        If xRow > 0 Then
            Name xDir & Application.PathSeparator & xFile As _
            xDir & Application.PathSeparator & Cells(xRow, "B").Value
        End If
        xFile = Dir
    Loop
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot of my excel file names:

[image: SCREENSHOTOFEXCEL]

Can anyone tell me whats the issue here ?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: `CSR\'s At Work.jpg` and `Carla\'s Pasta logo.tif` are invalid file names - you can't have a backslash in the name like that.

Comment: @dwirony It was originally saved by that name CSR\'s At Work.jpg. Also it doesnt work for other rows in the excel posted

Comment: @KaranNeginhalYou mean it created a folder named CSR and under that a Jpg file?

Comment: no it did not thats how its name is with \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have undergone with similar requirement.  I solved it using bit different approach.

Here's is exactly what I did:

1) I create Excel similar to yours.
2) Column A will have Old Filename
3) Column B will have New Filename
4) I will write DOS Command in Column C, using Excel Formula.

Once done, I will copy the data from Column C and create a BATCH File out of it. Once I run the BATCH File, it gets my work done. This formula assumes that you don't have any special characters.

Sharing the formula that I wrote in Column C:

> ="REN " & CHAR("34") & A2 & CHAR(34) & " " &  CHAR(34) & B2 & "" & CHAR(34)

And also adding screenshot of my Excel as reference. 
[image]

Comment: where do I keep all the files and the created bat file?All under the same directory?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I keep in the same files as the data files.